# Positioning multiple jquery dialogs

Tags: jquery, dialog

I have a page where users could open multiple dialogs.  The ajax call is to the itself with different parameters based on what was clicked.

each click i increment the variable clicked by 20 in an attempt to move the next dialog over 20 pixels instead of opening the next dialog on top of the previous.

getExtDetails.php

```
 $('.ivrKeyData').click(function(){
            var c = "<?php echo $_POST['click'];?>";
            if (c.length < 1){
                    c = 0;
            }
            var clicked = parseInt(c)+20;
            $( "#diag_"+id ).dialog({
                  title:'From '+header,
                  position: ['center',clicked],
                  .....
            });

  $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      data:"id="+data+"&click="+clicked,
      url:"getExtDetails.php",
      ....
   });
});

  a link on the page
    echo :<a href='#' id='".$id."' class='ivrKeyData'>".$id."</a>";
```

looking at the page source, the value of clicked is incrementing by 20, but the position is not moving...

Answer (score 1):

Try all numbers parse to integer.

```
var clicked = parseInt(parseInt(c)+20);
```

Comment: i got the same result. dialog directly on top of previous dialog.

Answer (score 1):

```
                  position: ({
                    my:'center+'+clicked
                    }),
```

solved this.